Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project
I am trying to open any class file on my java selenium project and getting the below error - enter image description here
This is not the first time working with this project. Recently I was getting errors related to use of older zulu version so I pointed to zulu 17 version. Any advice is appreciated.
I have tried to clean the workspace cache and also tried using latest lombok version. Neither worked for me

How old a release of Eclipse is this? Does it predate Java 17 support? Does it predate Java 17?

You would get that exact error if you run modern eclipse with an old lombok plugin. The fix is simple - update lombok. To do that, download lombok and run it as a jar file; it'll find your eclipse (or if you installed it in an unexpected and non-default location, you'll have the tell the lombok installer where), and just click the update button. It just copies itself into the right location, so, it'll be instantaneous.

this is resolved now. I installed a fresh copy of eclipse and then Lombok on top of it. I guess the existing copies were just corrupted. Appreciate anyone looking into this
